# Dependency created with Spring Boot used in Quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, quarkus

I have just started working on a project where I have to migrate an application from Spring Boot to Quarkus.

The project uses a private dependency of my company that is created using Spring Boot. A class of that dependency is configured using a yaml file.

Whenever I run the Quarkus project I get a NullPointerException that shows that the object of the class is not initialized at all which is pretty  weird since it should automatically autowire from Spring Boot in the dependency. The dependency itself has no problems since it works perfectly fine in the Spring Boot version.

Do I have to migrate that dependency to quarkus as well or is there any other solution that I can find?

Thank you

Comment: Does the code of the dependency contain Spring APIs?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by Spring APIs. The dependency is a jar compiled by maven that is created using Spring Boot.

Comment: @Ksi he means if your jar uses classes or interfaces which belong only to spring-boot, or in the pom has dependencies to other spring-boot components. For example https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-data-jpa if your jar uses spring-data you will need to add the quarkus spring data dependency

Comment: Yes, it does. I already tried including the quarkus dependencies for spring but it didn't make any difference. I think there are some classes that are not included in those quarkus dependecies